# LessPHP, Basset & Laravel - strange parse error

Tags: php, laravel, less, lessphp

I'm having a lot of difficulty getting LESS parsing to work nicely in Laravel.  I did some Googling and found Basset which seems to support LESS, and then found that it doesn't actually *parse* LESS.  So I installed LessPHP as well to do the parsing.

Now when I try to use the world's simplest LESS file:

```
@red: #f00;

body {
    background-color: @red;
}
```

It doesn't work.  I get a "parse error":

```
ErrorException
parse error: failed at `@red: #f00; ` line: 1
```

Does anyone know what incredibly obvious mistake I've made here?

What I've done so far:

1. Downloaded and installed Laravel
2. Added `"jasonlewis/basset": "dev-master"` and `"leafo/lessphp": "dev-master"` to composer.json
3. Run a `composer update`
4. Run a `php artisan config:publish jasonlewis/basset`
5. Edited the basset config to point to the `LessphpFilter`
6. Edited the `vendor/jasonlewis/basset/src/Basset/Asset.php` to fix a bug in compatibility with Laravel 4.1
7. Cleared application cache with `php artisan cache:clear`
8. Tried to load the page with the above LESS code

Comment: Hi gnack, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a work-around for this. If you add a dummy rule to the top of the file like so:

```
a {}

@red: #f00;

body {
    background-color: @red;
}
```

It works.

Comment: This will take some effort to test as I've moved away from this approach, but I'll vote it up and then accept it once I've had a chance to check it out.  Thanks so much for your response.